# Filling in desired lines in Scala

Tags: scala

I currently have a value of result that is a string which represents cycles in a graph

```
> scala result
String =
0:0->52->22;
5:5->70->77;
8:8->66->24;8->42->32;
. //
. // trimmed to get by point across
. //
71:71->40->45;
77:77->34->28;77->5->70;
84:84->22->29
```

However, I want to have the output have the numbers in between be included and up to a certain value included. The example code would have value = 90

```
0:0->52->22;
1:
2:
3:
4:
5:5->70->77;
6:
7:
8:8->66->24;8->42->32;
. //
. // trimmed
. //
83:
84:84->22->29;
85:
86:
87:
88:
89:
90:
```

If it helps or makes any difference, this value is changed to a list for later purposes, such like

```
list_result = result.split("\n").toList
List[String] = List(0:0->52->22;, 5:5->70->77;, 8:8->66->24;8->42->32;, 11:11->26->66;11->17->66;
```

My initial thought was to insert the missing numbers into the list and then sort it, but I had trouble with the sorting so I instead look here for a better method.

Answer (score 2):

Turn your `list_result` into a `Map` with default values. Then walk through the desired number range, exchanging each for its `Map` value.

```
val map_result: Map[String,List[String]] =
  list_result.groupBy("\\d+:".r.findFirstIn(_).getOrElse("bad"))
             .withDefault(List(_))

val full_result: String =
  (0 to 90).flatMap(n => map_result(s"$n:")).mkString("\n")
```

Here's a [Scastie session](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/tXrDmvH4SzS1oDm1EXJajg) to see it in action.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a `Map` as an intermediate data structure:

```
val l: List[String] = List("0:0->52->22;", "5:5->70->77;", "8:8->66->24;8->42->32;", "11:11->26->66;11->17->66;")
val byKey: List[Array[String]] = l.map(_.split(":"))

val stop = 90
val mapOfValues = (1 to stop).map(_->"").toMap

val output = byKey.foldLeft(mapOfValues)((acc, nxt) => acc + (nxt.head.toInt -> nxt.tail.head))
output.toList.sorted.map {case (key, value) => println(s"$key, $value")}
```

This will give you the output you are after. It breaks your input strings into pseudo key-value pairs, creates a map to hold the results, inserts the elements of `byKey` into the map, then returns a sorted list of the results.

Note: If you are using this in anything like production code you'd need to properly check that each `Array` in `byKey` does have two elements to prevent any `nullPointerExceptions` with the later calls to `head` and `tail.head`.

Answer (score 1):

The provided solutions are fine, but I would like to suggest one that can process the data lazily and doesn't need to keep all data in memory at once.

It uses a nice function called `unfold`, which allows to "unfold" a collection from a starting state, up to a point where you deem the collection to be over ([docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.7/scala/collection/Iterator$.html#unfold%5BA,S%5D(init:S)(f:S=%3EOption%5B(A,S)%5D):Iterator%5BA%5D)).

It's not perfectly polished but I hope it may help:

```
def readLines(s: String): Iterator[String] =
  util.Using.resource(io.Source.fromString(s))(_.getLines)

def emptyLines(from: Int, until: Int): Iterator[(String)] =
  Iterator.range(from, until).map(n => s"$n:")

def indexOf(line: String): Int =
  Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(':')))

def withDefaults(from: Int, to: Int, it: Iterator[String]): Iterator[String] = {
  Iterator.unfold((from, it)) { case (n, lines) =>
    if (lines.hasNext) {
      val next = lines.next()
      val i = indexOf(next)
      Some((emptyLines(n, i) ++ Iterator.single(next), (i + 1, lines)))
    } else if (n < to) {
      Some((emptyLines(n, to + 1), (to, lines)))
    } else {
      None
    }
  }.flatten
}
```

You can see this in action [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/UZvI4dKFSxSR1xyZR95OgQ/74).

What `unfold` does is start from a state (in this case, the line number `from` and the iterator with the lines) and at every iteration:

1. if there are still elements in the iterator it gets the next item, identifies its index and returns:

   - as the next item an `Iterator` with empty lines up to the latest line number followed by the actual line

     - e.g. when 5 is reached the empty lines between 1 and 4 are emitted, terminated by the line starting with 5
   - as the next state, the index of the line after the last in the emitted item and the iterator itself (which, being stateful, is consumed by the repeated calls to `unfold` at each iteration)

     - e.g. after processing 5, the next state is 6 and the iterator
2. if there are no elements in the iterator anymore but the `to` index has not been reached, it emits another `Iterator` with the remaining items to be printed (in your example, those after 84)
3. if both conditions are false we don't need to emit anything anymore and we can close the "unfolding" collection, signalling this by returning a `None` instead of `Some[(Item, State)]`

This returns an `Iterator[Iterator[String]]` where every nested iterator is a range of values from one line to the next, with the default empty lines "sandwiched" in between. The call to `flatten` turns it into the desired result.

I used an `Iterator` to make sure that only the essential state is kept in memory at any time and only when it's actually used.